# reduxForm : is showing old data some milliseconds and then refreshed with new data

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, redux-form, redux-form-validators

We are using React + React-Redux + Redux-Saga in our application, and the `withRouter` part of `react-router-dom` is used when connecting to the redux store.

`export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));`

Issue Steps:

1. I have all users listed on the users landing page.
2. I click on one of the users, then the redirect happens using the `withRouter`, `history.push` function, which kicks the redirect on `this.props.history.push(${REDIRECT_URL});`, this shows the current clicked user-profile data.
3. Now I come back to the users landing page
4. I click on another user, it again kicks in the `this.props.history.push(${REDIRECT_URL});`, and the previously visited users data is shown in a blink of an eye or some milliseconds, and then the newly clicked user-profile data is shown.

`reduxForm` connected for my application is below

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm({
    form: 'userProfile', // this form needs to be fixed I guess with passing other `(k,v)` to the `reduxForm`
    enableReinitialize: true,
})(UserInformation)));
```

Is there a way to fix this? to not show the previously visited users data? Appreciate help or pointers.

Comment: Is this behavior expected? I would be happy for pointers/references.

Comment: Can you share the implementation of <UserInformation /> in the main <App /> ?